# Applications that export JMeter-compatible JMX files?

Tags: tools, jmeter

Are there any other tools that can cooperate with JMeter tool? For example I record script and then export it to JMeter. I know that I can export jmx file to JMeter using BadBoy aplication but is there anything else?

Comment: Have you tried doing a Google search for "jmeter integration"?  Are you looking specifically for applications that produce files that JMeter can consume, or are you interested more generally in applications that can interact with JMeter?

Comment: I think about some applications that can export file whitch jmeter may work. eg I can not record something with JMeter so, I record it with BadBoy and than export this file to JMeter and continue my work with JMeter

Answer (score 2):

Bad boy is best and very simple tool to integrate with J-meter
you just need to capture test scenario in bad bou tool and than from file menu "expor it to j-meter", so .jmx file get created which you can use with j-meter